# is possible to fetch multi endpoint together in RTK Query?

Tags: rtk-query

I use RTK Query in react for fetching data from the server.
On a page, I must fetch pre-required data that the user must select in the form like provinces, cities, and ...
Currently, I call endpoints individually and handle them.
My question is, Is there any better way to fetch some endpoints together for better handling?